# Access host web data from a SharePoint add-in

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, jsom, sharepoint-addin

I am writing a SharePoint add-in to add list items to a host web list.  I use an AppContextSite object to fetch the list and add an item to it.  I then try to do an appSiteContext.load(listItem) call since this is how it is done through a normal client context object.  However it appears that this call does not work for an AppContextSite object (error says load is not a function).  Anyone know the equivalent call to load a list item to a host web list?  I have tried to research however MSDN provides very little documentation about the AppContextSite object.  Here is my code:

```
    function editHostList() {
    var hostWebContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, "https://urimdev.byu.edu/cmoodysite");
    var oList = hostWebContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Scripts Test');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'myItem');
    oListItem.set_item('Amount', '5');
    oListItem.update();

    hostWebContext.load(oListItem);
    hostWebContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
    );

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `context` to call `load` and `executeQueryAsync`, which is:

```
context.load(oListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
);
```